# Vision Transformer models in vit-keras

Tags: keras, model, vision-transformer

I have used vit_b32 and vit_b16 models in vit-keras. What are the other available models and their input image sizes in vit-keras? Are there any combined models (ResNet + Vit) available?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The other two options are vit_l16 and vit_l32. Each model is created using the [build_model](https://github.com/faustomorales/vit-keras/blob/28815edc5c24492612af726d1b2ca78295128d84/vit_keras/vit.py#L64) method, and the [image size is checked](https://github.com/faustomorales/vit-keras/blob/28815edc5c24492612af726d1b2ca78295128d84/vit_keras/vit.py#L98) in the build_model method. `image_size` must be a multiple of patch_size (patch_size is 16 for vit_b16 or vit_l16 and 32 for vit_b32 or vit_l32).